# How to make multiple LEFT JOINs with OR fully use a composite index?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am working on a timekeeping system and trying to determine that for each person, are they early or late for their scheduled shift.  The "TB_Scan" table originally had the person code and scan time which is a datetime field.  However, due to querying issues I was having, decided to add the scYear, scMonth and scDay fields thinking it might help.

It is a system that calculates how the users scan their fingerprints when they enter/leave the workplace. I don't know how it is called in English. I need to determine if the user is late in the morning, and if the user leaves work early.

This `tb_scan` table contains date and time a user scans a fingerprint.

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_scan` (
  `scpercode` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scyear` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scmonth` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scday` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scscantime` datetime,
  KEY `all` (`scyear`,`scmonth`,`scday`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

It has 100,000+ rows, something like this

```
scpercode scyear scmonth scday     scdateandtime
000001    2010      10     10      2016-01-10 08:02:00
000001    2010      10     10      2016-01-02 17:33:00
000001    2010      10     11      2016-01-11 07:48:00
000001    2010      10     11      2016-01-11 17:29:00
000002    2010      10     10      2016-01-10 17:31:00
000002    2010      10     10      2016-01-02 17:28:00
000002    2010      10     11      2016-01-11 05:35:00
000002    2010      10     11      2016-01-11 05:29:00
```

And this `tb_workday` table contains each date

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_workday` (
  `wdpercode` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wdshift` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wddate` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

It has rows with date sequence like this:

```
wdpercode  wdshift wddate
000001     1       2010-10-10
000001     1       2010-10-11
000001     1       2010-10-12
000001     1       2010-10-13
000002     2       2010-10-10
000002     2       2010-10-11
000002     2       2010-10-12
000002     2       2010-10-13
```

There is another `tb_shift` table containing shift time

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_shift` (
  `shiftcode` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shiftbegin2` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shiftbegin` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shiftmid` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shiftend` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shiftend2` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

shiftcode   shiftbegin2  shiftbegin  shiftmid  shiftend  shiftend2
        1     04:00:00     08:00:00  12:00:00  17:30:00  21:30:00 
        2     12:00:00     17:30:00  21:00:00  05:30:00  09:30:00
```

I want to determine that in each day, is the employee comes to work late or leaves work early, and at what time.

```
SELECT wdpercode,wddate,shiftbegin,shiftend,time(tlate.scscantime) wdlate,time(tearly.scscantime) wdearly
FROM tb_workday
LEFT JOIN tb_shift
  ON wdshift=shiftcode
LEFT JOIN tb_scan tlate 
  ON wdpercode=tlate.scpercode
  AND tlate.scyear=year(wddate)
  AND tlate.scmonth=month(wddate)
  AND (tlate.scday=day(wddate)
    OR tlate.scday=day(wddate)+1)
  AND tlate.scscantime>=ADDDATE(CONCAT(wddate,' ',shiftbegin),INTERVAL IF(shiftbegin2>shiftbegin,1,0) DAY)
  AND tlate.scscantime<=ADDDATE(CONCAT(wddate,' ',shiftmid),INTERVAL IF(shiftbegin2>shiftmid,1,0) DAY)
LEFT JOIN tb_scan tearly 
  ON wdpercode=tearly.scpercode
  AND tearly.scyear=year(wddate)
  AND tearly.scmonth=month(wddate)
  AND (tearly.scday=day(wddate)
    OR tearly.scday=day(wddate)+1)
  AND tearly.scscantime>ADDDATE(CONCAT(wddate,' ',shiftmid),INTERVAL IF(shiftbegin2>shiftmid,1,0) DAY)
  AND tearly.scscantime<ADDDATE(CONCAT(wddate,' ',shiftend),INTERVAL IF(shiftbegin2>shiftend,1,0) DAY)
```

Here is the example of an output:

```
wdpercode wddate      shiftbegin  shiftend  wdlate    wdearly
000001    2016-01-10  08:00:00    17:30:00  08:02:00  (null)
000001    2016-01-11  08:00:00    17:30:00  (null)    17:29:00
000002    2016-01-11  17:30:00    05:30:00  17:31:00  (null)
000002    2016-01-11  17:30:00    05:30:00  (null)    05:29:00
```

this `ADDDATE(CONCAT(wddate,' ',shiftbegin),INTERVAL IF(shiftbegin2>shiftbegin,1,0) DAY)` is for employees who work on night shift, so it has to add 1 day into the shift time

The problem is if I create an index for `scscantime`, MySQL refuses to use it for comparison (`>=`,`<=`,`>`,`<`). Please see this thread [Why does MySQL not use an index for a greater than comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691799/why-does-mysql-not-use-an-index-for-a-greater-than-comparison)

Because of this I created the `scyear`, `scmonth`, and `scday` fields and combine them in an index along with `scpercode`. And I have to make sure it calculates for workers working in night shift too so I have to add it with `OR scday=day(wddate)+1` condition.

Before I added the OR condition, the `EXPLAIN` result was 52 rows. But when I added the `OR scday=day(wddate)+1` condition, the `EXPLAIN` result became 364 rows, that means MySQL did not use scday part of the index. Is there any way to use the whole index, so the `EXPLAIN` result becomes 52 rows? I also tried removing the `+1` part and the result is also 52.

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare `table2.day = table1.month` and `table2.day = table1.month + 1`?

Comment: @KaeL oops sorry wrong field

Comment: What's the explain output of this: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.year=table1.year AND table2.month=table1.month AND table2.day=table1.day UNION SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.year=table1.year AND table2.month=table1.month AND table2.day=table1.day+1`

Comment: so is it the full query under **EDIT** in your post?

Comment: @1000111 Your solution with UNION is correct with the earlier queries, but I edited the question with a query I really needed

Comment: What's about now? `SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 tb21 ON tb21.year=table1.year
 AND tb21.month=table1.month
 AND (tb21.day=table1.day )
LEFT JOIN table2 tb22 ON tb22.year=table1.year
 AND tb22.month=table1.month
 AND (tb22.day=table1.day+2 )


UNION

SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 tb21 ON tb21.year=table1.year
 AND tb21.month=table1.month
 AND ( tb21.day=table1.day+1)
LEFT JOIN table2 tb22 ON tb22.year=table1.year
 AND tb22.month=table1.month
 AND (tb22.day=table1.day+3)`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @1000111 I think it's a full query I needed. In fact the query I am working on is a lot more complex than this. Please tell me if something is wrong with the query.

Comment: Try using `IN` clause?

Comment: Seriously consider storing dates as dates

Comment: @1000111 My query is taking too long to respond and I am not sure if your answer has a better performance than the old query. I'm so confused right now. Maybe I should post a clear question with the real query, table structure, and more explanations. I appreciate your help because my table has millions of records.

Comment: Try the query given in the `ANSWER` not from the `COMMENTS` @RedRomanov

Comment: Please show your table definitions, input, output and desired output for example data. Read about [mcve]s. Please edit info from your comments into your question.

Comment: @philipxy I followed your instructions. Is there still any chance someone will answer this question? I'm afraid this is not a new question anymore and no one will see it.

Comment: As Strawberry mentioned, why did you not use a date field?, but that aside, edit your post.  Clearly state what you are trying to do/get.  Your queries will mostly speak for themselves, but just joining generic "table1" and "table2" by dates give us no context to what you might NEED yet are not asking.

Comment: @DRapp These fields are for example. The query I am working on doesn't have the same field type like in the example.

Comment: Read *and follow* the comments & [mcve] page. Eg "input" and "output" (actual and desired) include (small) example table values and query plans etc. That code etc should exhibit the actual problem that you have. And please clarify your post.

Comment: @RedRomanov, yes, I understand.  Don't do "for example" fields. give context.  May not be actual live data, but live CONTEXT of what you are trying to do -- Our business tracks blah, blah.  I need a comparison of date activity of today vs 1 day forward vs 2 days forward for trying to assess patterns, such as buying/selling, inventory, whatever.  Give context.

Comment: I cannot understand your description of what info a row contains in your query results. If I give you a row (y1, m1, d1, v1), under what conditions (including for all possible cases where there cn be a NULL) will it be in table1? Or (y2, m2, d2, ,v2) in table2? If I give you a row (y1, m1, d1, v1, y21, m21, d21, y22, m22, d22), under what condirions will it be in your query result? PS Surely you don't want to use day + 1 but *date* plus 1 day? Eg not 2016 July 31 & 2916 July 32 but 2016 July 31 & 2916 August 1?

Comment: I just added the new definitions. Do you think it's better if I start a new question instead of appending to this one?

Comment: I started a new thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071966/how-to-make-multiple-left-joins-with-or-fully-use-a-composite-index-part-2

Answer (score 1):

From your query (readability formatted)

```
SELECT 
      table1.*, 
      tb21.year, 
      tb21.month, 
      tb21.day, 
      tb22.year, 
      tb22.month, 
      tb22.day 
   FROM 
      table1
         LEFT JOIN table2 tb21 
            ON table1.year = tb21.year
            AND table1.month = tb21.month
            AND (tb21.day = table1.day 
              OR tb21.day = table1.day+1)
         LEFT JOIN table2 tb22 
            ON table1.year = tb22.year
            AND table1.month = tb22.month
            AND (tb22.day = table1.day+2 
              OR tb22.day = table1.day+3)
```

Aside from your restrictive content provided, lets look at you trying to compare the data from same day to day + 1, +2 and +3.  Lets also assume just for this example you have only 10 days in the table represented as all June 1 - June 10, 2016 in both your Table1 AND Table2 tables.

Again, this is an assumption that each table has all 10 dates in question just for simplistic purposes of why so many records.  So, for Table 1 date of June 1, 2016, it will qualify with table 2 (tb21 version) and return TWO records. One for June 1 and another for June 2.  So now you have TWO records in your result.  Now, you do that again left-join to table 2 (tb22 version).  This time you are looking for 2 and 3 days out, of which you have June 3 and 4 in the table.  So you are getting a Cartesian result.  So, for the June 1 record in table 1, you now have 4 records as follows.

```
T1Year  T1Month  T1Day  T21Day T22Day
2016    6        1      1      3
2016    6        1      1      4
2016    6        1      2      3
2016    6        1      2      4
```

Now, lets say your table 2 has 3 entries on June 2 and 3 entries on June 3 and your data is going to super bloat.  This is why you need to provide more clarification on what you are trying to do.

So, not having true context on what you are looking for, ignore the fact it is not perfectly utilizing your index.  You have an OR based on the date via the day comparisons.  It should still utilize for the query anyhow.

Comment: Thank you for your help and I'm sorry for the trouble I caused. I'm doing my best as much as my English allows me to.

Comment: So if you could provide a [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), load up realistic data, @DRapp can get this solved for you. If you clarify any data uncertainties and assumptions.